# Layout is streching while cicking on InputView (Showing the keybad)

Tags: android, layout, imageview, stretch

I have an little issue related to the layout which is stretching when the keypad appears clicking on an InputView.

This is how the layout looks before clicking on ImageView:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNBjx.png)

This how the layout looks after :

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4lr8.png)

As you can the layout moves.

[EDIT] above XML layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum ="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgGameStatus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGameStatus"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Status..."/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInvite"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lib_choose_number"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="7"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="@string/lib_send"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="5">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

your help please.

Comment: Post your layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your empty listview pushes up the buttons, when it has been pushed up by the keyboard.

Insert

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
```

in your activity in the manifest like so:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing">
    </activity>
```

Comment: your recommandation works perfectly for me.                                          Thank you.

Comment: could you please accept the answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
```

in your activity in the manifest like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing">
</activity>
```